# $\binom {100} 0 \binom{100}{98}+\binom{100}2 \binom{100}{96}+\cdots+\binom{100}{98} \binom{100}0$

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof

$$\binom {100} 0 \binom{100}{98}+\binom{100}2 \binom{100}{96}+\cdots+\binom{100}{98}  \binom{100}0$$

Clearly the sum of bases is 98.
I have solved this problem algebraically by finding half of
Coefficient of $x^{98}$ in $$(1+x)^{100}(1+x)^{100}+(1-x)^{100}(1+x)^{100}$$
The answer comes out to be $$\frac{\binom{200}{98}-\binom{100}{49}}{2}$$

I wanted a combinatorial intuition behind it I framed a situation as if there are 2 bags and in total we need to pick 98 balls each contains 100 balls and we can only choose even number of balls from each bag and I'm stuck after this

Comment: The notation you are using for binomial coefficients is perhaps a bit dated and difficult to read (for example, exponents get confused with super-indices and so forth). I have edited your post to use the usual notation.

Comment: For a combinatorial solution: consider now putting all $200$ balls in the same bag and picking $98$, where $100$ balls are red and $100$ balls are blue. If the number of red and blue balls is even, you have an instance of your original problem. Thus, you need to decide what happens if the number of red balls is odd. You also need to notice that in the first problem there is an asymmetry (first pick red, then blue, or vice versa) that is lost in the second procedure, which should explain the $1/2$ factor.

Comment: Read about Vandermonde's identity. the proof is given in a comment by @Pedro.

Comment: And how would I count the number of ways to choose odd number of red balls @Pedro

Comment: What is " sum of bases " suppose to mean here ? Did you give a closed form for your sum of products in the third identity ? Sorry I am a bit confused. Not my expertise.

Comment: @RezaRajaei by 'combinatorial intuition ' I mean a combinatorial solution

Comment: @mick in $^nC_r$ I'm referring to r as the base here

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I noticed something odd when trying to generalize this.  If we pick $ 2 k $ balls (so $ k = 4 9 $ in the original question) from two bags with $ 1 0 0 $ balls each, then the number of ways to pick an even number of balls from each bag is $ \frac 1 2 [ \binom { 2 0 0 } { 2 k } + ( - 1 ) ^ k \binom { 1 0 0 } k ] $.  (I didn't prove this looking at coefficients of polynomials, just verified it with WolframAlpha for $ k = 4 6 , 4 7 , 4 8 , 4 9 , 5 0 $, and in my head for $ k = 0 , 1 $.)  It's the $ ( - 1 ) ^ k $ that surprised me, and it took a bit to track it down.

Comment: Further experiments suggest that we can change $ 1 0 0 $ to any other number $ n $ (and change $ 2 0 0 $ to $ 2 n $) without affecting this result.

Comment: I have now checked that this can be proved by examining the coefficient on $ x ^ { 2 k } $ in $ ( 1 + x ) ^ n ( 1 + x ) ^ n + ( 1 - x ) ^ n ( 1 + x ) ^ n $.  Actually, we can more generally say that, if you pick $ k $ balls (rather than $ 2 k $, so the number of balls might be odd now) from two bags with $ n $ balls each, then the number of ways to pick an even number of balls from the first bag is $ \frac 1 2 [ \binom { 2 n } k + \cos ( \frac 1 2 k \pi ) \binom n { k / 2 } ] $; that is, the second term vanishes when $ k $ is odd (which you could also figure out more easily by symmetry).

Comment: You write about "solving this problem", but you never actually state a problem.

Comment: Hi @AnshuGupta if you like the answer by Aig then you should accept it today so that it will be paid the bounty.  If you don't accept it, then in a couple of days it will automatically get half the bounty, but you'll still lose the whole bounty, so that's kind of a waste.  (Or if you don't like the answer, then you should comment to say what more you want.)

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused with that answer ,the solution isn't really clear  to me anyways I'll accept it I've posted my doubt do help if you can!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us imagine that we have two parallel rows of lamps. Red lamps with numbers from $1$ to $100$. And blue lamps with numbers from $1$ to $100$. As you stated the big sum in the title (denote it by $S$) is the number of combinations where $98$ lamps are switched on so that even number of lamps in every row is on. Let us prove that the number of combinations where $98$ lamps are switched on so that ODD number of lamps in every row is on is greater by $100 \choose 49$. Then it is obviously equivalent to $S=( {200 \choose 98}-{100 \choose 49})/2$ since ${200 \choose 98}$ is the number of all combinations of $98$ lamps switched on.

Let us try build a bijection between all the “even” and “odd” cases. Take some combination of $98$ lamps switched on. Let $i$ be the maximum number from $1$ to $100$ such that exactly one lamp with number $i$ is switched on. Inverse the two lamps. The “even” case became the “odd” one and vice versa. So the “even” and “odd” cases go in pairs, almost. The only group of cases when there is no pair is when all the lamps with same numbers are in the same state. There is clearly $100 \choose 49$ such combinations, and they are all “odd”. We are done.

Comment: Nice answer!  This also shows why the answer uses a $ + $ sign instead of $ - $ when $ 4 9 $ is replaced with an even number $ k $; again, there are $ \binom { 1 0 0 } k $ combinations where all pairs of lamps are in the same state, but this time they're all even.  (And when $ 9 8 $ is replaced with an odd number, then it's impossible to have all pairs in the same state, so the $ \binom { 1 0 0 } k $ term does not appear at all.)